# Inner Join without repeating value, keeping the rows of the first table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, inner-join

I have a table with the discount for each invoice.  For example:

```
Invoice Number|Discount
------------------------
    1         |   3
    2         |   5
    3         |   6
```

I need to pull these discounts to the invoice lines table (because they only apply to the total of the invoice, not to a particular line). At the same time I cannot lose any line.

Example: If the invoice 1 has 5 lines, I need all lines to show up (the 5 lines of the invoice), but I want the discount only once (for example, the first line would be enough).

Expected:

```
Invoice Number|Discount
------------------------
    1         |   3
    1         |   null
    1         |   null
    1         |   null
    1         |   null
```

If I have an `Invoice` table, and a `InvoiceLines` table that can be joined by the invoice number in both tables, how can I get the result that I need?

I tried this query without success:

```sql
Select  
   ROW_NUMBER() over(order by v.num_fra)as Rank,
   l.*,
   v.ctdrap_div as discount 
from ffac_vta v         --(invoicetable)  
join ffac_hla l         --(invoice lines table)
ON v.num_fra = l.num_fra
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way to do this...Basically, your sub query pulls the line item info - and gets the row number (partitioned by order number).  Then, you `LEFT OUTER JOIN` that subset to the table with the discount value ONLY when the row number = 1.  This approach doesn't require a `CASE` statement since the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` will give you `NULL` values for all row numbers above 1.

```
SELECT  Sub.*, 
        V.ctdrap_div AS [Discount]
FROM 
    (
    SELECT *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY v.num_fra ORDER BY v.num_fra) AS [Row Number]
    FROM ffac_hla L
    ) Sub
LEFT OUTER JOIN ffac_vta V
    ON v.num_fra = Sub.num_fra
    AND Sub.[Row Number] = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you should be able to just change your join to a left join.

```
Select  
  ROW_NUMBER() over(order by v.num_fra)as Rank,
  l.*,
  v.ctdrap_div as discount 
from ffac_vta v         --(invoicetable)  
left join ffac_hla l         --(invoice lines table)
ON v.num_fra = l.num_fra
```

Comment: This will return discounts for all records, irrespective of their Rank, which is not what the OP requires.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the key of your lines table or something to order your rows. Something like this. Also, do we have ROW_NUMBER() in SQL-Server-2008?

```
SELECT T.num_fra,
  CASE WHEN T.rank = 1 THEN T.Discount
    ELSE NULL AS Discount
FROM    
(
Select  
   ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY v.num_fra ORDER BY <<ADD THE KEY OF INVOICE LINES HERE>>)as Rank,
   l.*,
   v.ctdrap_div as discount 
from ffac_vta v         --(invoicetable)  
join ffac_hla l         --(invoice lines table)
ON v.num_fra = l.num_fra
) AS T
```

Comment: Thanks! Yep, I made it using Row_Number()

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT DENSE_RANK() over(order by v.num_fra)as Rank,
                num_fra,
                l.*,
                v.ctdrap_div as discount 
              FROM ffac_vta v         --(invoicetable)  
              JOIN ffac_hla l         --(invoice lines table)
                   ON v.num_fra = l.num_fra
)
SELECT num_fra
    , CASE WHEN Rank = 1 THEN discount ELSE 0 END
    , *
FROM cte;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use left join...
For more information about join, you can see this web site : https://www.quora.com/SQL-What-is-the-difference-between-various-types-of-joins

[difference between join image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OeS0.jpg)

I hope this help you

Comment: Since this is not an answer, it would be best left as a comment.  Answers should include a working solution and an explanation.  Furthermore, when linking to external sites, you should copy and paste the relevant material here to preserve the information should the external page be removed.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
select i.InvoiceID,Discount
from invoicedetail i 
left join invoicediscount id on i.invoiceID=id.invoiceid and i.linenumber=1
```

Comment: discount  is not a column name i wouldn't suspect, since the original query aliases a column as this name.

Comment: The OP can figure out how to apply it. The logic is correct. If the LineNumber doesn't restart at 1, then Wendy's solution is correct (except OP wants null instead of 0)

Comment: Also, 'LineNumber' is not a column - otherwise there would be no need to get the row_number.

Comment: @KeithL you seem to be upset with how this site works.  People give answers - and then other people give feedback.  In the case of your incomplete and incorrect answer, you can expect negative feedback.  And when you get that feedback, you should consider it rather than throwing a temper tantrum.

Comment: @KeithL I see you're deleting your angry comments instead of apologizing for your behavior.  Not sure if you should get half-credit for that.